# Is it possible to test e.g. google.com with angular cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I would like to create test which will do simple google search. Is it possible to test this over Angular CLI? how to change default localhost to "outside" web location?

Tnx in advance,

(as you can see i'm a cli noob and still learning, so please help!)

BR to all!

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to ask. Angular CLI is a Command Line interface for creating AngularJS projects. Would you like to host your project somewhere?

Comment: Basically i would like to test non angular web pages with angular cli and protractor. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

to serve the project on your localhost use

```
ng serve
```

in order to build your project use

```
ng build
```

This command will create a `dist` folder in which you compiled application resides. You can host the files from that folder on any http server to run your application.

Answer (score 0):

actually what you need to do is user protactor tu run a test and this is posible I recomend check some documentation on how to use protactor
http://www.protractortest.org/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you expound on this a bit, such as add details why and how Protractor would solve the users question? Also please mention if you are linked in any way to the product

Comment: the only thing you can use CLI for it is to run the test you build